# Django Rest Framework authentication with Custom User Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have multiple types of user in my django app: Employee and Patient. They have fields that are specific to each of them. They are implemented using the AbstractBaseUser model as below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser


class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'identifier'
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Patient'),
        (2, 'Employee'),

    )
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, default=1, blank=False, null=False)


class Role(models.Model):
    RoleName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)


class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    employment_start_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=True)
    employment_end_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=True)
    role = models.ForeignKey(
        Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='assigned_employees')


class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

I have a few questions with how to go forward with this:

1. How does just the choice in the User class limit the fields that a user has access to? If I had a HTML page would I create an Employee then a User would be created, or the other way round?
2. When I'm using Django Rest Framework, how can I implement a sign up and log in with the two different types?

I'm struggling to understand how this would work conceptually. Is like Employee and Patient a subclass of User? Or are they separate models? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your code you don't have two types of `User`. You have only one type - `class User(AbstractBaseUser)`. `Employee` and `Patient` are normal models that are only related to `User`.

If you wanted to create two types of `User` with actual inheritence, then you should do following:

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    # main user fields here

class Employee(AbstractUser):
    # employee fields here

class Patient(AbstractUser):
    # patient fields here
```

If you don't want to do this, your current approach is good. You can simply authenticate `User` in standard way. During creation you can make seperate forms for registering employee `User`, that creates automatically related `Employee` class. Similar for `Patient`. They will share only fields of `User` class with either approach.

To authenticate in different ways you can use custom authentication with `authenticate()` function. Read specifics in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if I did do it with actual inheritance how to the correct specific fields get called. Also my frontend will be in a mobile app language. Can I still  use forms then and pass them through or not? Thanks

Comment: If you set API, then you can do anything, endpoints and serializers will matter. " if I did do it with actual inheritance how to the correct specific fields get called." I have no idea, what you have in mind. If you use inheritance, then you can call fields of the model and parent model. In mobile you will probably have to set forms that will send different `json` messages to your API and create proper child object using serializer.